# [Drools 7.x]Dynamic rules Update at runtime(rules stored in Amazon S3)

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, kie, drools-kie-server

I am using drools 7, and currently we are loading all the rules and creating rule engine during service start-up. However there is a requirement of updating the rule engine whenever rules are updated. I came across the concept of KieScanner that scans for the updates, in the specified maven repositories. However, in my case, these rules are stored in external resource(Amazon S3).

I went through multiple resources available but ironically none of them have a proper reference/guide. There are no clear examples or documentation around how to use KieScanner in cases where rules are present in external repository.

This was the most accurate reference I could find- [Drools 7.x dynamically load rules at runtime without using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494609/drools-7-x-dynamically-load-rules-at-runtime-without-using-maven) but concept of KieContainerLocal is not present in drools 7.x

In drools 5, we can achive this customResource(s3 in this case) that implements BaseResource and using ResourceChangeScanner and ResourceChangeNotifier, it polls the data from S3(with the custom implementation of getInputStream()). I went through multiple resources in drools 7, but couldn't find a way to do this.

Can anyone please help me understand if dynamic updation of rules is possible in drools, if we have rules in external resource? If yes, do we have any documentation or examples around the same?